# Are there any other tools wizards can use as they would a wand?

Tags: harry-potter

Is wands the only tool used for spellwork? Are there any wizards that use staffs, like Gandalf, in Harry Potter? Is there any mention of other tools you can use to perform spells?

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104928/why-did-witches-and-wizards-in-harry-potter-need-wands-to-perform-magic-well and certainly https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2622/are-there-any-spells-that-a-wizard-witch-can-cast-without-a-wand-in-the-harry-po which sounds like a dupe.

Comment: @Valorum Was the staff from the books or the movies?

Comment: @BernardtheBear - Only from the movies. In the book he had a staff but didn't use it for magic (as far as we're aware).

Comment: The inconsistencies between the books and the movies are quite vast.

Comment: @BernardtheBear - As I've said on several occasions, if you made a *truly faithful* version of the books, the films would each be nine hours long and unwatchable crap.

Comment: That's not an issue, but was he using the staff as he uses a wand? Was it stated that he could use it to perform spells or did it have that singular function?

Comment: @BCdotWEB, that is not what I am asking! Surely, the wand isn't the only tool used for spellwork, or is it?

Comment: @BernardtheBear - Ollivander says you can use anything as a "focus" for magic. On the other hand, we never see anyone use anything other than a wand.

Comment: We do, however, see wizards (mostly Dumbledore) perform magic using only their hands. I think it's safe to say that if you can cast spells with no instrument at all, you can use any instrument to help you cast spells. It's just that wands are specially crafted to make casting spells easier for each individual Witch or Wizard, which is fairly important in the case of kids who've never casted a spell before going to school to learn how to cast spells.

Comment: @marcellothearcane I don't see how this is a duplicate. The answers on the other question don't mention any other tools used by wizards.

Answer (score 1):

There are many OBJECTS indeed:

- Enchanted Coins: In Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Hermione Granger creates fake, enchanted Galleons that are used for communication between members of Dumbledore's Army.
- Howler: A Howler is a blood-red letter sent to signify extreme anger or to convey a message very loudly and publicly.
- Hand of Glory:The Hand of Glory is described as a large shrivelled hand displayed on a cushion in Borgin and Burkes, a Dark Arts shop in Knockturn Alley.

AND you may refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magical_objects_in_Harry_Potter
for more info

Comment: Those are all enchanted objects, they don't channel a wizard's magic to help them cast spells in the way a wand does.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as none of these are "tools you can use to perform spells"